# Recursive function to check if a given number is Fibonacci

Tags: python, function, recursion, fibonacci

I'm new to python and I'm am having problems building a recursive function that checks if a given number is a Fibonacci number.

This is my code.

```
def isFib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return (n - 1) + (n - 2)
    
    if isFib(n) == 1 or isFib(n) == isFib(n - 1) + isFib(n - 2):
        return True
```

It should print True in both cases, but instead it print True and False, and I can't find what's wrong

```
print(all([isFib(i) for i in [1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]]))
print(all([not isFib(2*i) for i in [1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]]))
```

Comment: Hint: What does isFib(13) return?

Comment: The first part of your function is an `if` statement. If `True`, it returns a value - if `False`, it also returns a value. So, the second part of your function cannot possible execute, and the function isn't recursive (since you don't call the function again in either `return` statement).

Comment: Check your function. Sometimes you return a number, sometimes you return `True`, and sometimes you return `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your function is an `if` statement. If `True`, it returns a value - if `False`, it also returns a value. So, the second part of your function cannot possible execute, and the function isn't recursive (since you don't call the function again in either `return` statement).

More generally, what you're doing will never work. The logic seems to be: "a Fibonacci number is the sum of the previous Fibonacci number and the number before that, so I can reverse that logic by computing `n - 1` and `n - 2` and if they are Fibonacci numbers, then so is `n`" - or something like that.

But that doesn't work: 5 is a Fibonacci number, but (5-1) is not, so the logic breaks right there. If you were thinking only the sum needed to be a Fibonacci number: 13 is a Fibonacci number, but (13-1) + (13-2) = 23 and that's not a Fibonacci number either.

An easy way to solve this would be to just generate a Fibonacci sequence and return `True` as soon as the number you're checking comes up:

```
def is_fib(n, seq=None):
    if seq is None:
        seq = [0, 1]
    # n is Fibonacci if the last number in the sequence is
    # or if the last number has not yet past n, then compute the next and try again
    return n == seq[-1] or (seq[-1] < n and is_fib(n, seq + [seq[-2] + seq[-1]]))


print([is_fib(i) for i in [1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]])
print(is_fib(23))
```